# How to catch error text when executing sh command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have a Jenkinsfile with the following function

```
private void execureOnServer(String command, String label = "") {
    script{
        withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "mycreds", keyFileVariable: 'ID_RSA')]) {
            def result = ""
            try {
                result = sh(label: "${label}", script: "ssh -i ${ID_RSA} -o LogLevel=error -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP \"${command}\"", returnStdout: true).trim()
            } catch (err) {
                telegramSend(" DEPLOY FAILURE: ${PROJECT_CODE} ${PROJECT_ENV} by ${AUTHOR}\n\n${COMMIT_MESSAGE}\n\n${result}")
                throw new Exception(result)
            }
            println result
        }
    }
}
```

Following telegram message is received

```
 DEPLOY FAILURE: min test svc_tasks by  

 

hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
```

Following logs in Jenkins

```
+ ssh -i **** -o 'LogLevel=error' -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' myser@10.0.4.98 'docker service update --force --image=10.0.3.60:5050/myproject/min_svc_centrifugo_queue:test centrifugo_svc_queue'
Error response from daemon: service centrifugo_svc_queue not found # <<=== THIS IS THE MESSAGE I WANT TO SEE IN TELEGRAMM MESSAGE
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -s --insecure --max-time 10 --data-urlencode 'chat_id=-7777' --data-urlencode 'disable_web_page_preview=1' --data-urlencode 'text= DEPLOY FAILURE: min test by  

 

hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1' https://api.telegram.org/mybottoken/sendMessage
```

I'm OK not having AUTHOR and COMMIT_MESSAGE.

It sends telegram message without the `${result}` part or `java.lang.Exception:` instead, BUT prints error message text in the logs (I guess `println result`) is doing it's job.

What I want is to send error message text using my `telegramSend()` function using my `execureOnServer()` function

I tried removing `\n` line breaks

Comment: try to include err into a message. also use `throw err` instead of `throw new Exception(result)`. by throwing a new exception you are loosing original error message.

Comment: Can you add what's being printed when you do `println result`

Comment: @ycr Edited post to include Jenkins logs